# read csv with pandas with this kind of dataset

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have some troubles to read a dataset like this:

```
#    title
#    description
#    link (could be not still active)
#    id
#    date
#    source (nyt|us|reuters)
#    category
```

example:

```
court agrees to expedite n.f.l.'s appeal\n
the decision means a ruling could be made nearly two months before the regular season begins, time for the sides to work out a deal without delaying the 
season.\n
http://feeds1.nytimes.com/~r/nyt/rss/sports/~3/nbjo7ygxwpc/04nfl.html\n
0\n
04 May 2011 07:39:03\n
nyt\n
sport\n
```

I tried:

```
columns = ['title', 'description', 'link', 'id', 'date', 'source', 'category']
df = pd.read_csv('news', delimiter = "\n", names = columns,error_bad_lines=False)
```

But it put all the information into the columns title.

Do someone knows a way to deal with this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `\n` as a delimiter for csv, what you could do is set the index equal to the column names, and then transpose, i.e.

```
df = pd.read_csv('news', index=columns).transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to note:

1) Any delimiter more than 1 character long is interpreted by Pandas a regular expression.

2) Since 'c' engine does not support regex, I have explicitly defined engine as 'python' to avoid warnings.

3) I had to add a dummy column because there is a '\n' at the end of the file, i have later removed that column using drop.

So, these lines will hopefully result what you want.

```
columns = ['title', 'description', 'link', 'id', 'date', 'source', 'category','dummy']
df = pd.read_csv('news', names=columns, delimiter="\\\\n", engine='python').drop('dummy',axis=1)
df
```

I hope this helps :)